# Import SQL query from MYSQL to MsAccess

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I need to create sql statments to import data from an existing MySQL database into MsAccess.
Has anyone got any ideas on the best way i can do this?

This is the code i used to create the database in MySQL just to give an idea of the tables etc.

```
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS horsedb;
 USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`horse` (
`HORSE_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Colour` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Sire` INT NULL,
`Dam` INT NULL,
`Born` YEAR NULL,
`Trainer_id` INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`HORSE_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`showsite` (  
`show_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,  
`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`show_id`));

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`judge` (  
`Judge_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,  
`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,  
`Address` VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`Judge_id`));

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`event` (
`Event_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
`Show_id` INT NOT NULL, 
`Event_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Judge_id` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Event_id`),
INDEX `show_id_idx` (`Show_id` ASC),
INDEX `judge_id_idx` (`Judge_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `show_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`Show_id`)  
REFERENCES `horsedb`.`showsite` (`Show_id`)  
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `judge_id`    
FOREIGN KEY (`Judge_id`)    
REFERENCES `horsedb`.`judge` (`Judge_id`)  
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`entry` (
`Event_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT, 
`horse-id` INT NOT NULL, 
`Place` INT NULL, 
INDEX `horse_id_idx` (`Horse_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `horse_id`    
FOREIGN KEY (`Horse_id`)
REFERENCES `horsedb`.`horse` (`Horse_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`prize` ( 
`Event_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT, 
`place` INT NULL,  
`money` INT NULL, 
 ));

USE horsedb; CREATE TABLE `horse`.`trainer` (  
`Trainer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,  
`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`Trainer_id`));
```

Comment: Are you looking to work with the data in access, or move the entire database to access?  (just ad edit...MSAcess uses it's own flavor of SQL that doesn't much match other languages.  You'll be rewriting most queires.  Seems a luittle backwards moving from a relational db to access)

Comment: @Twelfth Your comment suggests that Access is not a "relational database". Do you really believe that?

Comment: @GordThompson - No, simply suggesting any other relational DB to access causes significant rework and is a 'downgrade' at best...it makes a better data access tool than a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct method for transferring MySQL tables into Access would be to install the MySQL ODBC driver ([MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)) and then use an ODBC connection to Import (not Link) the tables from MySQL. For more detailed instructions see:

[Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Access](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html)

Comment: I have done that, i was curious to know if there was a sql query conversion from mysql to access to import, rather than migration/import where you use wizards rathan than code

Comment: @user2991848 There are third-party tools that claim to perform conversions from one SQL dialect to another (e.g., one [here](http://dbconvert.com/queries.php) that specifically mentions Access<->MySQL). If such a tool performed as advertised then I suppose you could use `mysqldump` to "export" a MySQL database to a .sql file, use the tool to convert the MySQL SQL statements to their Access equivalent, and then use the result to "import" the data into Access. However, given that such a transfer is normally a one-time thing, the "wizard" approach seems preferable (to me, at least).